# block google play ads in my app

Tags: android, admob

Google play is advertising on AdMob, and this poses a problem with submitting android apps to alternative app stores like Samsung.

Here is an example of how the ad looks like in admob

[image]

I want to block this ad as it's against Samsungs developer agreement to have apps linking or advertising other app stores. I tried adding filters for "play.google.com" and a text filter for "Google Play", however none of that really worked. Worse I can't find a way to get the ad to be displayed on my end.

Comment: You're not fully describing what you want to do.  Are you trying to submit an application to the Samsung alternative app store?  What do you want to do?

Comment: When submitting to Samsung, my app gets rejected because of the google play ad as it's against the agreement to advertise any other app store.

Comment: hey did u got any solution to block adds in android ??

Comment: No I did not. Instead I ended up removing admob ads and submitting it to Samsung app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. You need to put in the comments box at the bottom that you have included standard admob advertising, stressing that the ads are not your own links or games. Worked for me after they rejected mine the first time.