# admob - How block google play ads in my app

Tags: android, admob

Most of the time only Showing Google play Store ads in my app. I am using admob. There is any way to block google play ads in my app?

Answer (score 0):

In your admob settings, you can go to mediation and choose what networks you use.  Turning off house ads will probably do it, but may make your fill rate plummet.

Comment: Sorry i think you misunderstanding.. I need block play store promotion ads only... check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706458/block-google-play-ads-in-my-app

Comment: I think you misunderstand how admob works-  it feeds you ads.  You have a limited set of controls on how to block some of them-  basically you can block networks and certain categories.  That's all you can do.  If that isn't enough, find another ad network that doesn't put in those advertisements.

Comment: Ok.. admob - Manage Filter Settings - Exact Word = "ebay" , Now i blocked ebay ... i am right? Can i block like play store promotion ads?

Comment: You can try adding a filter for "google" or "play".  It may work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this as you are cutting out part of your revenue but you can veto any ad url from SiteAndApps->AdFilters. Just add https://play.google.com/store to there.